# unable to select item from react-native-dropdown-picker

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

am using React-native-dropdown-picker, however am unable to select any item from the dropdown list, the items are being overlapped by the below view.
I have tried adding position:'absolute, zIndex:2 but still the itemlist is being overlapped as follows:
[image]

I have written the code for dropdown component as follows

```
 return (
    <View>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {console.log('new array', dateArr)}
        {console.log('arr', arr)}
        <Icon
          name="arrow-left"
          size={20}
          color="#fff"
          style={{marginTop: 12}}
        />
        {console.log('----------date', dateArr)}
        {dateArr != null && (
          <DropDownPicker
            onValueChange={(value) => onValSelect(value)}
            items={dateArr}
            itemStyle={{
              // justifyContent: 'flex-start',
              flexDirection:'row'
            }}
            
            containerStyle={{height: 40,width:'80%',zIndex:2}}
          />
        )}
       
      </View>
      <DaysInAWeek daysInAWeek={daysInAWeek} />
    </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#FE017E',
    // height: 56,
    width: '100%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    padding: 10,
  },
});
```

onValSelect() is as follows:

```
 function onValSelect(val) {
    if (val.length > 1) {
      let arr = [];
      for (let i = val[0]; i <= val[1]; i += 86400000) {
        let date = getMonthDate(new Date(i));
        arr.push(date);
      }

      console.log('final arr', arr);
      setDaysInAWeek(arr);
    } else {
      console.log('single date', new Date(val));
      setDaysInAWeek(new Date(val));
    }
  }
```

please let me know the issue any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey did you find any solution for this? I added zindex in parent view to solve the issue but ended up with another issue. Now I cannot select anything from the list.

Comment: @Reema yea, if you read the doccumentation it is mentioned, zIndex in the parent container might result to such problem, use style prop of dropdown picker for whatever styles you want, that fixed mine

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If somebody still didn't get this, here something I found
This is all related to the parent element, so if DropDownPicker component does not have a parent element with some height then this would not let you select even if you see the options.

just give parent element `minHeight:300px` or any height you want
Example -

```
<View style={{minHeight: 300}}>
          
             <DropDownPicker
               items={timeslots}
               defaultValue={this.state.selected2}
               containerStyle={{height: 40}}
               style={{backgroundColor: '#fafafa'}}
               itemStyle={{
                 justifyContent: 'flex-start',
               }}
               dropDownStyle={{backgroundColor: '#fafafa'}}
               onChangeItem={(item) => 
                 this.setState({
                   selected2: item.value,
                 });
               }
             />
        
         </View>
```

Comment: Yes, This helps me. Added a minimum height to parent VIEW. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem in this way:

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
      ...
<View style={[style.viewContainer, Platform.OS === 'android' && open && style.androidContainer]}>
      <DropDownPicker
        open={open}
        setOpen={setOpen}
...
```

styles:

```
   viewContainer: { marginHorizontal: 16, zIndex: 1 },
    androidContainer: {
      minHeight: 500,
      marginBottom: -428,
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 <View style={{ zIndex: 999}}>
       <DropDownPicker
           ...
         />
```

adding Zindex for View worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Make the zIndex: -1 for the components that are overlapping and zIndex: 1 for the dropdown picker

Answer (score 0):

```
 cost dataArr=[
        {label: 'USA', value: 'usa'},
        {label: 'UK', value: 'uk' },
        {label: 'France', value: 'france'},
    ];   
<DropDownPicker
    items={dataArr}
    defaultValue="Select Country"
    containerStyle={{height: 40}}
    style={{backgroundColor: '#fafafa'}}
    itemStyle={{
        justifyContent: 'flex-start'
    }}
    dropDownStyle={{backgroundColor: '#fafafa'}}
    onChangeItem={item => this.setState({
        country: item.value
    })}
/>
```

I guess the problem is with your item style. can you change the flex-direction to column?

Comment: hi, have added the code for onValSelect, it was a style issue have fixed but  am still unable to select anything from the dropdown, could you please help?

Comment: style prop did help, but adding flexdirection for the parent container is making it untouchable

Comment: Adding `itemStyle={{
        justifyContent: 'flex-start'
    }}`
in this style?
What is purpose of flex direction? please explain.

Comment: the items would start from the left of the margin

Comment: labelStyle:This property gives full control over the label
`
labelStyle={{
    fontSize: 14,
    textAlign: 'left',
    color: '#000'
}}`

Comment: use justify content attribute for label alignment
`itemStyle={{justifyContent: 'flex-start|flex-end|center'}}`
I hope that will help.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the DropDown Direction worked for me.

dropDownDirection ="TOP"

Answer (score 0):

```
const heightDropItem = 40 // your height items        
<View style={{minHeight: open ? (items.length + 1) * heightDropItem : heightDropItem}}>
                <DropDownPicker
                  style={{
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    borderRadius: 4,
                    borderColor: colors.textHiragino,
                    fontSize: 16,
                  }}
                  placeholder="2022年"
                  open={open}
                  value={value}
                  items={items}
                  setOpen={setOpen}
                  setValue={setValue}
                  setItems={setItems}
                  multiple={false}
                />
              </View>
```